# Probability density function as limit of multinomial distribution?

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

I'm working on a problem but I need a result wich I'm not sure if it's true or how to prove it.

Let $X$ be a  random variable , where $P(X \in A) = 1$, with $0< \int_Adx < \infty$. One can partition $A$ in $\bigcup_{k=1}^{K}A_k$. Now assume $$P(X \in A_k) = \frac{\int_{A_k}\lambda(u)du}{\int_A\lambda(u)du},$$ for any set $A_k$.

I want to verify if the density of $X$ is $f(x) = \frac{\lambda(x)}{\int_A\lambda(u)du}$. My first idea was seeing it as a multinomial with $n=1$,$K$ possible values (this solution would make extensions easier). When $K\rightarrow\infty$ and $\int_{A_k}dx \rightarrow0$ for all $A_k$  this should give me the result I'm looking for.

It doesn't look too complicated, but I might lack measure-theory knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very ambiguous formulations. Since you used $dx$, I would assume that $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$. The definition of density functions for $X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is then defined as a Lebesgue measurable function $f(x)$ such that
$$
P(X\in A)=\int_Af(x)dx
$$ 
where $A\in\mathcal{B}$, the Borel algebra of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $dx$ is the usual Lebesgue measure. By your definition the answer is obvious.